# What is the term for people who only eat home raised meat?

Tags: terminology, omnivorous-diet

Many non-meat eaters make this choice because of the way commercial meat is produced and because of the negative impact that it has on the animal's well being. Most or all of this negative impact can be eliminated in a home farm.

Is there a term that defines people who only eat home raised meat?

Comment: "Carnivores" would be accurate :P

Comment: The term "locavore" describes somebody who only eats food produced close to home. Such a person is sometimes motivated by concerns about commercial meat production.